# Iptables redirecting

Tags: apache-http-server, iptables, redirection

I have set up a Personal hotspot using Hostapd. But this hotspot is not connected to the internet but I do have Apache installed on it. What I am trying to achieve is to redirect all the clients (that are connected to my hotspot) to my apache page when they visit another website. So basically redirect all traffic to my Apache page.

What I have tried is :

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.150.1:80
```

But with this iptable the clients only get redirected to my Apache webpage when I share an internet connection with my hotspot. But without the internet connection they do not get redirected.

Comment: is this linux? in which case one could tag it as linux and that may help in you getting an answer. If it's windows i'd be interested in how you got iptables on windows

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason is because prior to connect to a website, the browser needs to resolve the name it wants to connect to via a DNS request. Since the hotspot is not connected to the internet, there won't be a response with any IP and the browser will not try any further.

To achieve what you are planning, you should create a DNS server, capture the DNS requests with a similar `iptable` rule (since some clients will not use the hotspot-specified DNS server) and answer all of them with your apache's IP.

If you use `bind` as the DNS server, you could set a master zone named "." in your named.conf (comment out the default "." zone with the hints information). Then, create a zone file which contains a wildcard record for the apache IP.